# Unity - trading card game architecture

Tags: unity-game-engine, architecture

I'm trying to develop a TCG(trading card game) in Unity(I'm Unity newbie) and currently stuck on the architecture of the project and the card effects in particular. Coming from web development background for me all the logic and card effects should be on the server but going through some tutorials for Unity I think the logic should be on the client and I should use a simple room-based server to notify for player actions. Is that correct?

To summarize - where the game logic should be(e.g. card effects, rounds etc)? On the client or on the server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I actually worked on one of the major TCG's out now for iOS/droid, so this is coming from experience.  You definitely want all game logic and rules to be on the server.  Do not trust your client to be the source of truth for any game outcomes etc. People will be able to hack that by tampering with the data sent back to the server.  They don't have to decompile the game to do that, it can be done merely by sniffing the net traffic.

That said, you may end up with some duplicated logic on both client and server, only so that you can enforce game rules and display the outcomes without always hitting the server.  However, your server is always the source of truth and the client is just there to accept input and display outcomes.

The general flow was the client would send a message requesting a new game to the server.  The server would respond with the cards for each side and the opening move for the first player.  Then the client would simply parse each move and display the outcome.  On the cards objects we had methods for many of the actions, such as DrainHealth() and BuffAttack().  When called, these methods would trigger things like particle effects and sound fx attached to the card script.

Comment: Thanks for the advice Tyler. We also were considering solution similar to what you described but with all those confusing "advanced tutorials" we started questioning our decision.

Comment: One last thing. Were you using self-hosted server or any on the available solutions like photon (if you were using photon which of their solutions did you choose?)

Comment: The tutorials are never fun.  I remember what a pain they were to code on our game.  For our server, we used php/mysql on amazon AWS.

Comment: @TylerDay In your TCG, how did you handle defining all the cards? Did you use some kind of config file to store all the cards and their properties, or did you have an abstract Card class and many many classes that inherited from it? Perhaps even some other way than these? Could you people elaborate on how this aspect was handled? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yeah the effects should be on the client, I assume your game will be turn based right? You might want to take a look at photon then:

https://doc.photonengine.com/en-us/realtime/current/getting-started/realtime-intro

They have a loot of good tutorials about their API and it's well documented :) 
Hope that helps you, 
good luck

Comment: yup turn based. I was just considering photon solutions. But if the logic is on the client doesn't that make the game hackable

Comment: I don't think so, you have to keep in mind that the game gets compiled it is not like you can see the javascript files as you can in web development...